# Force open alphabetical keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

I have a tab which when clicked on will force open the keyboard. This works fine, but there is also a numerical input field on this app, so when I use this and go back to the tab which opens up the keyboard it opens up a numerical keyboard (number pad). How can I make it so it forces open the normal keyboard?

Here's the code that deals with the keyboard opening and closing on tab changes:

```
public void onTabChanged(String tab){
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if(tab.equals("keyboardTab")) {
        // open keyboard
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
    }
    else {
        // close keyboard
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `"keyboardTab"` contains some text field you may set attribute `android:inputType="text"` for it. This field has to receive focus before keyboard is forced to open.

Comment: There is no text field; the keyboard is forced open on tab change (as the code shows). I want to know how to force open a normal keyboard, much like you can tell the application to open a certain keyboard when selecting certain input fields.